# Debian 8 multiple PHP are these safe methods?

Tags: php, linux, server, debian

At work i want to upgrade our system to PHP7. It is currently at PHP5.6.
We have a different folder structure, as we have all our code in the /home/user directory.

I am not a server guy, i only code. But i know some linux basics.
I came across phpbrew. Is it safe for me to use? as we have a different folder structure then most have.

I dont want to mess up my development server, so it is important for me that i can switch back to 5.6. The server is running debian 8 and we use apache2.

I also came across this article:
https://lornajane.net/posts/2016/php-7-0-and-5-6-on-ubuntu
Is this a safe way to do what i want?

Any other suggestions are also welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "safe"? So that you can easily switch back from one version to the other? Or some sort of security concern? "safe" is too broad a word, can you be specific about what is concerning you?

Comment: Well, with safe i mean: safe to switch back to php5.6 without any problems. As i am not a server guy. Our current code base runs on 5.6, so when i see that the system is not working on 7, i need to switch back

Comment: The process described in that link looks plausible. Possibly other online resources might confirm it. Why not make a quick VM and try it out?

Comment: Well i tried it with a VM, that is what i normally do. But we have a heavily modified server that is modded by someone with almost no credible server experience. 0 documentation, and a crazy setup. We also have a custom framework that needs a specific server setup, also with 0 documentation. So i thought this is the best way to do it. After the upgrade im gonna port the whole to laravel :) And make a normal dev server

Comment: sounds like a good plan. Is your current dev server a VM? You could clone it, then make the changes and run both in parallel. If not, you could shut it down briefly, image it, and then use the image to build a VM or another physical box. That way you've got the crazy setup copied, and you can test PHP7 along with that stuff, with no risk to the current environment. That would be my advice.

Comment: @ADyson i did exactly like you said. The dev server is a physical server. Made an image and a VM of it. Thank you very much. If you can make a answer of it i will mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process described in that link looks plausible. Possibly other online resources might confirm it. Why not make a quick VM and try it out?

Is your current dev server a VM? You could clone it, then make the changes and run both in parallel. If not, you could shut it down briefly, image it, and then use the image to build a VM or another physical box.

That way you've got any custom server setup copied across reliably with minimal effort, and you can test PHP7 along with that stuff, with no risk to the current environment. That would be my advice.